# LInux-File Globbing

Tags: linux, globbing

I have an assignment and it asks me to

> Display files in /usr/bin that do not begin with a through v

it then asks me to

> Display files in /usr/bin that contains at least two numeric digits

I've tried everything I could think of, I cant figure these two commands out.

Comment: #1: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173785/ #2: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171399/ -- did these not work for you? What exactly have you tried? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Use find:

```
find /usr -not -name "v*" -type f
```

`-name` lists all files which match **v** and then arbitrary characters

`-not` inverts this

-`type f` only lists files, not directories

```
find /usr/bin -type f  -name "*[0-9]*[0-9]*"
```

the same as above
[0-9] stands for **one** arbitrary digit, the asterisks ( * ) for arbitrary characters in between, before and after the digits.

Don't forget the quotation mark, otherwise the name expression is not evaluated by find for the results, but by the shell, before they get passed to find

Comment: This will list files in the subfolders as well. if this is not desired, add `-maxdepth 1` to the command or use `ls`